# /bin/bash giving a segmentation fault upon startup

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, segmentation-fault, redhat

I am getting a segmentation fault from bash when I try to SSH to a remote server (running RHEL 4.4.5-6). After providing my credentials, the SSH client spits back the "Last login: ..." information, and then just hangs.

Out of curiosity, I pressed Ctrl-C and was able to get to a bash prompt. However, it's not the "usual" prompt that I see (it usually has my username, the server hostname, etc).

```
login as: xxxxxxx
xxxxx@xxxx's password:
Last login: Fri Mar 30 14:33:41 2012 from xxx.xx.xx.xxx

-bash-4.1$ echo $0
-bash
-bash-4.1$
```

I tried to run /bin/bash from GDB. After a medium-sized wait time, I finally got a SIGSEGV error:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /bin/bash

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08067ab5 in yyparse ()
(gdb)
```

The last (significant) changes that I've made to the system was installing GNU screen (using yum install screen). Screen seemed to hang as well when I tried to start it (I'm assuming because it tried running bash, and got the same segfault).

Edit:

I tried running rpm -V:

```
-bash-4.1$ rpm -V bash
-bash-4.1$
```

Here are my .bash* files:

.bashrc:

```
# .bashrc

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
```

.bash_profile:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
```

.bash_logout:

```
# ~/.bash_logout
```

.bash_history is quite long. I erased it, tried logging in again, and got the same results.

Comment: Have you tried posting the backtrace to the bash developers?

Comment: I haven't... what do you recommend? I could email the details to bug-bash@gnu.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're recursively sourcing your .bashrc from inside itself, which in a short test here does indeed lead to a segmentation fault. Removing that part from your .bashrc should hopefully fix the problem.

Comment: A-ha! I didn't think of that. I changed my bashrc to check for /etc/bashrc instead and it loads perfectly. Thanks!